# Git Push a Local PodSpec

Tags: ios, git, github

I am currently trying iOS developing on my own and my project has now become quite large, so i want to git push to github just in case i screw up.

However, as i tried to git push, it always gives this

`"large files are detected, File Pods/nighthawk-webrtc/lib/libWebRTC-8444-arm-intel-Release.a is 118.31 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB"..`

It is the local `"nighthawk-webrtc-8444.podspec"` that i have causes the problem.

I sort of thought it may have to do with the .gitignore file, because i include the PODS for push, so i have my .gitignore written as this

```
    # Xcode
.DS_Store
*/build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap
*.xccheckout

#CocoaPods
Pods
```

to exclude the Pods library. However it doesn't work. It still trying to git push the entire local nighthawk-webrtc-library to github and i still end up with the same error.

This nighthawk-webrtc-library is a pod spec created by a third part, when i run pod spec lint, it gives me the following validation errors:

```
-> nighthawk-webrtc (8444)
    - ERROR | The name of the spec should match the name of the file.
    - WARN  | There was a problem validating the URL www.perch.co.
```

which i do not have idea whether it has anything to do with git push, but even if it has,  i can't seem to edit it.

To be just clear: I wish to git push the local pod spec to the github, but i do not wish to git push the entire library like what the system is currently doing. Anyway to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Although the files are git ignored, I'd bet you a dollar that you need to remove them from the local git, and them commit AND push that. Ignore changes are NOT RETRO-ACTIVE, i.e. if a file was added you need to remove it.

Drop to a shell and type:
`git rm <FILE(S)>`
OR use SourceTree/Tower or whatever you prefer

Comment: i have done the following commands on terminal already git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "fixed untracked files" but it doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: Are the files still under status if you go git status. It might be best to not ignore them first of all, untracked them from your repository by deleting and committing that delete, and THEN ignoring them. Not to mention you might have to "FORCE" delete, besides untrack

Comment: I used git ls-tree -r master --name-only to check the currently tracked files, and all the Pods files are not included. However, when i do a push, the same error that "Pods/nighthawk-wertc....... is too large".. Couldn't figure out why at all.

Comment: I have also tried to delete the files and git push, still getting the same error.. Totally cluless